# Where's located the declaration of messageSource in Grails?

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.0

### Background

We have some legacy internationalization for field labels that are stored in the database, so I tried to make a "merged" messageSource. If the code exists in database, return, if not, use PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource to look in the i18n.

### Problem

For some reason the cachedMergedPluginProperties is caching the wrong file for the locale. For example, if I search for en_US, I receive pt_BR messages (the key of the Map is en_US, but the properties are pt_BR).

I declared my messageSource as follows:

```
messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource) {
  messageBundleMessageSource = { org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource m ->
    basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    } 
}
```

The inner bean is beacause of Grails won't let me have two beans of type `MessageSource`.

Am I declaring `PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource` different from the default of Grails? In which file of Grails I can see this bean declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the declaration inside `I18nGrailsPlugin`, and it's a bit more detailed then mine:

```
String baseDir = "grails-app/i18n"
String version = GrailsUtil.getGrailsVersion()
String watchedResources = "file:./${baseDir}/**/*.properties".toString()
...
 Set baseNames = []

        def messageResources
        if (application.warDeployed) {
            messageResources = parentCtx?.getResources("**/WEB-INF/${baseDir}/**/*.properties")?.toList()
        }
        else {
            messageResources = plugin.watchedResources
        }

        if (messageResources) {
            for (resource in messageResources) {
                // Extract the file path of the file's parent directory
                // that comes after "grails-app/i18n".
                String path
                if (resource instanceof ContextResource) {
                    path = StringUtils.substringAfter(resource.pathWithinContext, baseDir)
                }
                else {
                    path = StringUtils.substringAfter(resource.path, baseDir)
                }

                // look for an underscore in the file name (not the full path)
                String fileName = resource.filename
                int firstUnderscore = fileName.indexOf('_')

                if (firstUnderscore > 0) {
                    // grab everyting up to but not including
                    // the first underscore in the file name
                    int numberOfCharsToRemove = fileName.length() - firstUnderscore
                    int lastCharacterToRetain = -1 * (numberOfCharsToRemove + 1)
                    path = path[0..lastCharacterToRetain]
                }
                else {
                    // Lop off the extension - the "basenames" property in the
                    // message source cannot have entries with an extension.
                    path -= ".properties"
                }
                baseNames << "WEB-INF/" + baseDir + path
            }
        }

        LOG.debug "Creating messageSource with basenames: $baseNames"

        messageSource(PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource) {
            basenames = baseNames.toArray()
            fallbackToSystemLocale = false
            pluginManager = manager
            if (Environment.current.isReloadEnabled() || GrailsConfigUtils.isConfigTrue(application, GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.CONFIG_PROPERTY_GSP_ENABLE_RELOAD)) {
                def cacheSecondsSetting = application?.flatConfig?.get('grails.i18n.cache.seconds')
                if (cacheSecondsSetting != null) {
                    cacheSeconds = cacheSecondsSetting as Integer
                } else {
                    cacheSeconds = 5
                }
            }
        }
```

Since Grails don't let you have two beans of type `MessageSource` I had to copy this code and adapt to mine "merged" messageSource.